# How to create keyword,value pair json from pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
        Keyword    Value
   0         K1       V1
   1         K2       V2
   2         K3       V3
```

And I would like to return a json like so:

```
{
    "K1":"V1",
    "K2":"V2",
    "K3":"V3"
}
```

My approach right now is to basically convert to dictionary first with `df.to_dict(orient='list')`, extract the Keyword and Value lists, go through the lists and create a separate dictionary, then convert to json.  I would like to know if there is a more elegant and direct way to do this from the dataframe itself. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
df.set_index('Keyword')['Value'].to_dict()
```

or

```
dict(zip(df['Keyword'], df['Value']) )
```

Comment: Yes thank you! Not sure what is occurring but it works :D

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
In [661]: df.set_index('Keyword')['Value'].to_dict()
Out[661]: {'K1': 'V1', 'K2': 'V2', 'K3': 'V3'}
```